# How can you get Copilot to turn on in all Dev Containers in VS Code?

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer, github-copilot

I would like to use the Github Copilot extension each time I develop in VS Code, even when I have opened a project in a Dev Container. Right now, I have to manually install Copilot in each project each time the Dev Container opens.

I know I could specify "Github.copilot" in the devcontainer.json "extensions" list, but these aren't my projects, so I want a solution that will turn it on for me but not impose it on others.

Answer (score 9):

You can specify default extensions that will open in every Dev Container, regardless of the configuration. Open the VS Code Settings, search for Dev Containers, and scroll to Dev Containers: Default Extensions. Then add "Github.copilot" to that list.

[image: Screenshot of Dev Containers settings in VS Code]

Comment: The updated VS Code settings will apply to subsequently created container images.

Comment: FYI, you can access the Extensions list (ctrl + shift + X) and open the 'Manage' menu (the gear) and click on the option 'Apply extension to all profiles'

Comment: Make sure you search for "Dev Containers" (with space) and not "devcontainer" - the later will not give the same search results.